# Unauthorized JWT Authentication

Tags: angular, mongodb, spring-boot, jwt

I am trying to make spring boot authentication with jwt and mongodb and i am sending the Request Body with angular and i tried even with postman and i get this error:

> Unauthorized error: Failed to instantiate com.example.Educart.models.User using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments
> controler

```
    @PostMapping("/signin")
    @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt,
                userDetails.getId(),
                userDetails.getUsername(),
                userDetails.getEmail(),
                userDetails.getAdress(),
                userDetails.getnum(),
                roles));

    }
```

jwt.ts

```
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: Unauthorized");
    }
```

Comment: even if I right wrong password, it gives the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to great empty user contractor